# Remove Blank Lines from String SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, carriage-return

I have a field in my SSRS report that has multiple carriage returns, for example:

```
 First, get materials



 Next, glue them all together

 Last, let dry for two hours
```

All six lines are in in the one field, its not 7 rows.  I know I can replace/remove the carriage returns, but what I am really looking for is to be able to just remove the blank lines.  I would still want to keep the carriage returns on the lines that have text, like this:

```
 First, get materials
 Next, glue them all together
 Last, let dry for two hours
```

I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you might be stuck with an all or nothing situation. Is there a common character that ends or starts the following line to find and insert a carriage return next to?

Comment: No, no common characters, its it field where people can just type freely into, so it may or may not have carriage returns at all, let alone common preceding/ending characters.

Comment: What if you replaced all double carriage returns with an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that multiple return carriage/new line characters could be present in each line, while your expected result is divide each line by only one return carriage or new line character.

I think it can be avoided using Regex replace method (Yes, you can use Regex in SSRS).

If you are sure your source is generating the new line using carriage return you can use:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!MultilineText.Value,
"\r\r+",Environment.NewLine)
```

Otherwise if your source is generating the next line via new line character (code 10 in ascii) you should use:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!MultilineText.Value,
"\n\n+",Environment.NewLine)
```

Note most Windows systems use \r\n to determine an end of line, replace accordingly to your environment.

**UPDATE:**

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!MultilineText.Value,
"\r\n[\r\n]+",Environment.NewLine)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried both ways and neither one changed the field.  The formula didn't error out or anything, the display just remained unchanged.

Comment: @jenhil34, I am pretty sure the expression works, the problem is that we don't know the characters used to produce the new line in your data. I've updated the expression, give it a try. If it doesn't work check if the empty lines are caused by multiple white spaces and not using carriage return or new line characters.

Comment: See my answer. I am saving this one above to my code library however. Really smart idea.

Comment: I am using the last expression and it works well but I will mention that you can add a `.Trim()` at the end to remove the last \r\n or you might get a blank line at the bottom of the cell where the value is presented.

Answer (score 0):

I got a good answer that I just figured out. My Address2 (second line of an address) is not always there in all the rows. So I was able to use a conditional to put a vbCrlf in or put Nothing in if there was no value in Address2.

So now, each concatenated line stacks up nicely without empty rows if there is no Address2. Probably could do this with Environment.Newline instead of the vbCurliff.

```
=Trim(Fields!IPA_Addr1.Value) & IIF(LEN(Trim(Fields!IPA_Addr2.Value)) > 0, vbCrLf, Nothing) & Trim(Fields!IPA_Addr2.Value) & IIF(LEN(Trim(Fields!IPA_Addr2.Value)) = 0, vbCrlf , Nothing) & Trim(Fields!IPA_City.Value) & ", " & Trim(Fields!IPA_State.Value) & " " & Trim(Fields!IPA_Zip.Value)
```